# World download for servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I was playing a server which consists of insane builds. I wanted to download these maps, but when I tried the world downloader mod, it does not work. Is there a solution to download it without using any mods?

Comment: Ask the server owners for a copy of the world? That would be the most certain way.

Comment: Isn't your real question why the mod doesn't work? Why switch to a completely different piece of software instead of trying to get the original software to run?

Answer (score 1):

You can't download server worlds without mods, however if you are willing to use mods i recommend Schematica http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1285818-schematica

**Before downloading anything contact the creator for permission**